# Installation of 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04 server fails with "Unable to install busybox-initramfs"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-13.04

I tried installing the 64-bit 13.04 Ubuntu server on a fairly generic superMicro box with dual OCZ SSD's I plan to software RAID.  The install failed with a "Unable to install busybox-initramfs" message.  This appears to be a bug documented [on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1117292).  (I got the same error message even when ignoring the second SSD.)

I checked console 4 for details:

```
apt-install or in-target is already running, so you cannot run either of them again until the other instance finishes.
You may be able to use `chroot /target ...` instead.

in-target: Unexpected error; command not executed:
`sh -c debconf-apt-progress --no-progress --logstderr -- apt-get -q -y --no-remove install busybox-initramfs`
```

I'm not sure what to do with this error message without sifting through the installer code, but the person who reported the bug originally on launchpad suggested that he found a workaround by "preseeding the installation with linux-server". Does anyone have any idea what this means / how to do this?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html

Comment: I too am having this problem. Hoping there is a command line switch to fix this.

Comment: 13.04 is obsolete, at this point.  Either install 13.10, the current stable version, or I recently installed the 14.04 beta, which was the smoothest install yet.

Comment: Even though the question was asked regarding 13.04, I just had this error installing 14.04, so it's still current.

Comment: Still current with 14.10 trying to install with LVM.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue and did two things to solve it. Dont exactly know, which one solved it...
Installing to LVM too.

1. erased the USB stick again, with the Ubuntu `Boot Media Creator`(dont know the exact english name sorrz)
2. /boot partition separate, outside of LVM, formated with ext3(with error it was ext4)

After that, the installation succeeded.